# How can I download Image File from an URL to ByteArray?

Tags: android, image, download

following is my code:

```
private byte[] downloadImage(String image_url) {
            byte[] image_blob = null;
            URL _image_url = null;
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                _image_url = new URL(image_url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) _image_url.openConnection();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            try {
                conn.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            try {
                inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                inputStream.read(image_blob);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                conn.disconnect();
            }
            return image_blob;
        }
```

What I am trying to do is to get the byte array of an Image. Use it in a parcel to transfer it to another activity.

Using this code a NullPointerException is reported. Can any one say what is wrong?

Comment: Would you mind tell us on which line the NPE occurs? And please add the full stacktrace to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try it like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(imageUrl);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
int imageLength = (int)(entity.getContentLength());
InputStream is = entity.getContent();

byte[] imageBlob = new byte[imageLength];
int bytesRead = 0;
while (bytesRead < imageLength) {
    int n = is.read(imageBlob, bytesRead, imageLength - bytesRead);
    if (n <= 0)
        ; // do some error handling
    bytesRead += n;
}
```

And by the way: The NullPointerException is caused because `image_blob` is null. You need to allocate the array first before you can read data into it.

Comment: This seems to work on some files, however some other files do not download this way. It seems that for some reason it is not always possible to know the length of the content in advance...

Comment: can't import DefaultHttpClient class. Do i have to add a dependency or library for this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather then sending image, you can send path of image which is download in cache. You can just use this methods to proive image path and download image into local path.

```
    private String createLocal(String surl) {       
    URL url;
    try {


        url = new URL(surl);


        String tempname=String.valueOf(surl.hashCode());

        File root=getCacheDir();

        File localfile=new File(root.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+tempname);

        localfile.deleteOnExit();
        if(!localfile.exists()){
            InputStream is=url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(localfile);
            CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
        }
        return localfile.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    final int buffer_size=1024;
    try {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer_size];
        for(;;) {
            int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
            if(count == -1)
                break;
            os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your byte[] image_blob is null,you must new enough space like that before you use it:

```
image_blob = new byte[enough];
inputStream.read(image_blob);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static byte[] getByteArray(String url) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
}
```